# connecting PX4FLOW optical sensor with pixhawk for indoor navigation using mavros

Tags: navigation, ros, drone.io, px4

Hey guys I am currently trying to build a autonomous indoor navigation drone whose navigation is done by scanning qrcodes. I am currently doing a trial version where I have connected my pixhawk 2.4.8 with my laptop and I am giving commands through Mavros. It is working but It requires gps to takeoff so i thought of using aPX4 optical flow sensor which can be used instead of gps for indoor navigation.
I have a PX4Flow and a pixhawk 2.4.8. I connected the PX4Flow to the pixhawk 4 via I2C per the instruction below.
Link: https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-px4flow-overview.html
The green, blue, and orange LED lights on PX4Flow were flashing when connected.
However, I do not see any optical flow data on mission planner and there in no tick mark on Initial Setup>>optional hardware>>Optical Flow section where it should be shown.

When I connect the PX4Flow to PC via USB cable, I see optical flow data on mission planner.
I have not used PX4 optical flow  sensor before so if anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it .
when i tried with an another pixhawk still the same problem of enable is there but now i am getting values of the optical flow sensor so i calibrated it as per the steps provided in the link above.

I tried to give it commands through mavros and i has able to arm and disarm and also change the mods by giving commands but still i wasnt able to takeoff when i give command for takeoff this is the error comming "Something went wrong. Topic timed out."i looked at the topics and there wasn't any topics related to px4flow optical sensor to publish data to the pixhawk.
I think the problem is with the enabling part of optical flow in pixhawk if anyone has faced this or any similar problem